# Sending Command to device in Eclipse hono

Tags: eclipse-hono

I'm experimenting with command and control in Hono and got this:=>

[image]

#### Error Message

> No credit available for sending request

anyone knows how to deal with this?

Comment: It is kind of hard to tell without knowing a little more about your setup. What kind of device do you want to send a command to? MQTT, HTTP? The error itself indicates that there is no device connected and listening for commands.

Comment: Through HTTP. Device-id: 4711 which is assigned to DEFAULT_TENANT. I followed the steps mentioned in getting started documentation on eclipse hono's site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your device is not ready to receive any commands. In case of HTTP, the devices inform their readiness to receive commands using a telemetry or event message with an additional parameter named hono-ttd. Below example illustrates a telemetry message request (to sandbox) with hono-ttd value as 60 seconds using curl.

`curl -i -X POST -u sensor1@DEFAULT_TENANT:hono-secret -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data-binary '{"sensor1": 5}' http://hono.eclipse.org:8080/telemetry?hono-ttd=60`

In the above case, after 60 seconds the device is no longer ready to receive any commands.

I would suggest that you first send a request from the device as above with the hono-ttd value. Then try sending a command to that device before expiry of the hono-ttd.